# Bootstraps Grid System on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, grid-system

We are using Bootstraps on a website but Internet explorer doesn't seem to be using the grid system from Bootstraps. We have a class assigned with class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" but on Internet Explorer 11 it is stretching across the screen. Here is an image of the problem http://wikicopy.com/loginproblemIE.png The background stretches across the whole screen. It works fine on Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: Can you give us the relevant HTML markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your site rendering in compatibility mode? if so, adding the `meta` tag below should fix the issue.

> IE Compatibility modes
>   Bootstrap is not supported in the old Internet Explorer compatibility modes. To be sure you're using the latest rendering mode for IE, consider including the appropriate  tag in your pages:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```