# Bootstrap panels appear differently in Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small program using bootstrap and i am using the bootstrap panels.  It works like i wish in Chrome but not in IE.

This is the code I am working with:
On the pictures it is poosibel to see the differenct in the appearing.

```
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            background-color:#fcfcfc;
        }
        *, *:before, *:after {box-sizing:  border-box !important;}
        .row {
         -moz-column-width: 30em;
         -webkit-column-width: 30em;
         -moz-column-gap: .5em;
         -webkit-column-gap: .5em; 

        }
        .panel {
         display: inline-block;
         margin:  .5em;
         padding:  0; 
         width:98%;
        }
</style>
  </head>

<body>
<div id="content" class="container">

        <h3>Apps</h3>

<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">App1</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="list-group">

                <a href="NewApplication.aspx?id=0700" class="list-group-item">App1.1</a>
                <a href="NewApplication.aspx?id=0703" class="list-group-item">App1.2</a>
                <a href="NewApplication.aspx?id=0705" class="list-group-item">App1.3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">App2</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App2.1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App2.2</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App2.3</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App2.4</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App2.5</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App2.6</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App2.7</a>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title">App3</h3></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="list-group">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App3.1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App3.1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App3.1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App3.1</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">App3.1</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

IE

[image: Internet Explorer]

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Comment: Provide code snippets

Comment: possible solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21311466/bootstraps-grid-system-on-internet-explorer

Comment: I tried to add this line from the other solution but it made no difference <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
Internet Explorer do not accept prefix so I needed to change the css a bit

```
.row {
     -moz-column-width: 28em;
     -webkit-column-width: 28em;
      column-width: 28em;
     -moz-column-gap: .5em;
     -webkit-column-gap: .5em; 
      column-gap: .5em;
```